# How to print messages in an API endpoint in next.js

Tags: next.js

I was wondering how I can print messages for debugging in an API endpoint in next.js,

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    ...
    # print someting here
}
```

I used console.log to try to print out something, but it doesn't show in my terminal or on the inspect console.

Thanks!

Comment: ```console.log``` does not log in the terminal of the working process ?!

Comment: `console.log` will definitely log something to the terminal where you started the dev server. Are you accessing/making a request against that API route for it to actually run? Can you provide the full code you have in the `handler` function?